# get value of object in javascript

Tags: ecmascript-6, es6-class

I try to understand the following code (you can copy it to [ES 6 Console](https://es6console.com/) )

```
myarr = [{id:'1',title:'title1'},{id:'2',title:'title2'}] ;
mystate = { allVotes: myarr };
console.log(mystate);

const { allVotes } = mystate; //This line I do not understand
console.log(allVotes);
```

The line

```
const { allVotes } = mystate;
```

seems like a short way to set a variable with the name of the key filled with the value from the object. Can someone this explain? I would do it much uglier with:

`const allVotes2 = mystate['allVotes'];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is called a destructuring assignment and you can read about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment